# Interpolation algorithm with GDAL in R

Tags: gdal, r, geotiff-tiff

I'm currently having some problem while trying to create a GeoTIFF file.

```
require(raster)
require(sp)
require(rgdal)
require(gdalUtils)
library(rgeos)

map <- readOGR ('MyShapefile.shp',layer='MyShapefile')
grid <- paste(sortie,"grid.tif",sep="")
gdal_grid(src_datasource='MyShapefile.shp',dst_filename=grid,zfield='In_ATMO',a="invdist:power=2.0:smoothing=1.0",of="GTiff",ot="Float32",l=mod,output_Raster=T)
sauv<-paste(sortie,"test_In_ATMO.tif",sep="")
gdalwarp(srcfile=grid,dstfile=sauv,tr=c(7.0,7.0),of="GTiff",ot="Float32",overwrite=T)
```

This is the code sample I use to create my GeoTIFF file, but it really looks like it isn't in an high definition.

[image: gtiff]

My CSV data looks like this

```
long;lat;In_ATMO
55557754;14454489;4
......
```

And with this data I create a shapefile that I use to create a GeoTIFF file. If asked, I can share those files to help answering my question..

Is there anyone who knows how can I get a better definition for my TIFF ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have finer resolution, `gdalUtils::gdal_grid()` has an option `outsize` to define output dimensions.

You might have noticed `gdal_grid()`, returns message like:

```
class       : RasterBrick 
dimensions  : 256, 256, 65536, 1  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
```

(The output was RasterBrick as you have specified by `output_Raster=T`).

Then you can double nrow and ncol by giving an `outsize = c(512, 512)`. 
Borrowing your example, it would be:

```
gdal_grid(src_datasource='MyShapefile.shp',dst_filename=grid,zfield='In_ATMO',
          a="invdist:power=2.0:smoothing=1.0", outsize = c(512, 512), 
          of="GTiff", ot="Float32", l=mod, output_Raster=T)
```

And the output raster is in higher definition:

```
class       : RasterBrick 
dimensions  : 512, 512, 262144, 1  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
```